After updating Firebase Pod project cannot find FirebaseStorage
After running pod update Firebase and updating firebase to the latest version project does not want to compile anymore. This is the version it updated from
Installing FirebaseABTesting 10.29.0 (was 10.1.0)
Installing FirebaseAppCheckInterop 10.29.0 (was 10.1.0)
Installing FirebaseAuthInterop 10.29.0 (was 10.1.0)
Installing FirebaseCoreExtension 10.29.0 (was 10.1.0)
Installing FirebaseCoreInternal 10.29.0 (was 10.1.0)
Installing FirebaseInstallations 10.29.0 (was 10.1.0)
Installing GoogleDataTransport 9.4.1 (was 9.2.0)
Installing GoogleUtilities 7.13.3 (was 7.10.0)
Installing PromisesObjC 2.4.0 (was 2.1.1)
Installing nanopb 2.30909.1 (was 2.30909.0)

Xcode 15.4. is complaining
Framework 'FirebaseStorage' not found
Also it is complaining
Showing Recent Errors Only
/Users/XXX/Code/Project/Project-app/Pods/FirebaseStorage/FirebaseStorage/Sources/Storage.swift:73:12: Value of optional type '(any StorageProvider)?' must be unwrapped to refer to member 'storage' of wrapped base type 'any StorageProvider'
But that is not my code. That is from Pods.
Did anyone had similar issues? I have cleanded the project, deleted derived data, rebooted my mac and the problem still persists.

